# git push error: HTTP request failed: The requested URL returned 504

Tags: git, github, tortoisegit

I am getting the error git did not exit cleanly (exit code 128) in Tortoise Git while pushing my changes to master in GITHub

```
git.exe push -v --progress  "origin" master:master

Pushing to https://github.com/myproj/Net.git
error: The requested URL returned 
error: 504 while accessing 
https://github.com/myproj/Net.git/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack
fatal: HTTP request failed

git did not exit cleanly (exit code 128) (63228 ms @ 22-12-2012 23:57:48)
```

I already referred [How to resolve "git did not exit cleanly (exit code 128)" error on TortoiseGit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9617336/how-to-resolve-git-did-not-exit-cleanly-exit-code-128-error-on-tortoisegit)

But i am using HTTPS and not SSH. I mean i cloned using HTTPS url from GITHub.
Also i have no idea how to get SSH generated!

[image]

What will be fix?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As mentioned here:

> The 504 Gateway Timeout error is an HTTP status code that means that one server did not receive a timely response from another server that it was accessing while attempting to load the web page or fill another request by the browser.
>
> This usually means that the other server is down or not working properly.

And that is coherent with the current [GitHub status](https://status.github.com/) (22d of Dec.):

> We are currently experiencing major service outages across all services.

So while the cause is quite punctual and specific to the current network issue on GitHub side, you question can help others with a similar error message:

504 means: the upstream server is in trouble.