# Git push error, fatal: HTTP request failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I have been working on this rails project for weeks (it is deployed using Heroku), pushing to GitHub frequently without a problem. I am now getting this error:

```
error: The requested URL returned error: 504 while accessing
https://github.com/my_git_name/my_repository_name.git/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack
fatal: HTTP request failed
```

Any idea what might be causing this? Thanks!

Comment: Is the push or any particular file in the push really large?

Comment: No, I think it was an issue on Github's end.

Comment: It's usually that or a big file(s) with 504's. Glad to hear you're all good.

Answer (score 1):

I have [already seen that 504 error message](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14007813/6309) in conjunction with GitHub trouble.

And that seems consistent with last night GitHub status message:

> 21:51 UTC We are currently working to resolve problems affecting a subset of repositories on a single fileserver.

So, if the error message is now gone, that would confirm the possibility of a server-side (GitHub) issue, as opposed to a more permanent client-side problem.