# git push master to github fails with no error. where are the logs?

Tags: git, github, push

After migrating to a new 64 bit GNU/Linux distro, I tried to push some commits in my local repository to github.
But it fails silently.

```
git push origin master --verbose --progress
```

This prints the following line. and simply exit silently.

```
Pushing to https://github.com/myrepository.git
```

It is not asking me, username and password as it used to do before. It does not even give any error. The exit code is 128.

```
echo $?
128
```

Does git has any log somewhere, which i can look into to see what went wrong? Where do i start troubleshooting this?

### Update:

I should have checked the dmesg output earlier!.
Following is what i found in it.

```
[17612.051408] git-remote-http[14249]: segfault at 7f5ce16e2630 ip 00007f5ce16c1df9 sp 00007fff863bd660 error 7 in libcrypto.so.1.0.0[7f5ce15ef000+1b1000]
```

Looks like the problem is in that library, i shall try to recompile that library again.

Comment: possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9617336/how-to-resolve-git-did-not-exit-cleanly-exit-code-128-error-on-tortoisegit (note: has 16 completely different answers; apparently this error can be caused by nearly anything...)

Comment: @Wooble Thanks for the link. If git does not keep any log of what happened, i guess it is going to be hard to troubleshoot.

Comment: I should have checked. dmesg earlier. don't know why i didn't think about it. it had a segfault reported in it!!

Comment: Since you got the answer, answer your own question to help other people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of dmesg (as well as /var/log/messages) had the following line in it.

```
git-remote-http[14249]: segfault at 7f5ce16e2630 ip 00007f5ce16c1df9 sp 00007fff863bd660 error 7 in libcrypto.so.1.0.0[7f5ce15ef000+1b1000]
```

Hence. i believe, i only have to reinstall libcrypto.so.1.0.0 library.