# Not able to clone any git repositories - exit code 128

Tags: git, github

I've never experienced this before. All of a sudden, I am not able to clone any git repositories (via https also). This is what I see:

```
deployer@TimeBox:~$ mkdir eye
deployer@TimeBox:~$ git clone 'https://github.com/kostya/eye.git' eye --verbose
Cloning into 'eye'...
deployer@TimeBox:~$ echo $?
128
deployer@TimeBox:~$ wget https://github.com/kostya/eye.git
--2015-08-20 20:12:22--  https://github.com/kostya/eye.git
Resolving github.com (github.com)... 192.30.252.131
Connecting to github.com (github.com)|192.30.252.131|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://github.com/kostya/eye [following]
--2015-08-20 20:12:23--  https://github.com/kostya/eye
Reusing existing connection to github.com:443.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: ‘eye.git’

eye.git                                              [  <=>                                                                                                        ]  73.30K   278KB/s   in 0.3s   

2015-08-20 20:12:23 (278 KB/s) - ‘eye.git’ saved [75064]
```

I am able to make https connections, but for whatever reason git does not let me clone any repositories and just silently quits with a 128 error code.

I have a valid ssh key also and I tried to regenerate it with ssh-keygen which did not help :( -- also, this is a public repository so it is not a case of needing to import the ssh public key into github.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9617336/how-to-resolve-git-did-not-exit-cleanly-exit-code-128-error-on-tortoisegit

Comment: Yes, it's not a key issue at all.

Answer (score 0):

I was pulling my hair out over this, then decided to run dmesg and tail /var/log/messages. Sure enough that showed git was segfaulting. Very strange issue.

Rebooting the machine resolved the immediate problem and so far the server is working correctly but I suspect some kind of intermittent hardware fault.