# What does this Ruby code mean?

Tags: ruby, git, backup, gitlab

I am trying to make a backup restore of gitlab and it kind of works but th command line always says that the restore of the repositories failed. I think I found the conditional statement in the code which responsible for the [failed] statement. Has someone a clue what this is doing or know a direction in which I should go to find my mistake?

```
 if Kernel.system("git clone --bare #{path_to_bundle} #{project.repository.path_to_repo} > /dev/null 2>&1")
puts "[DONE]".green                                                                                                                                                               
          else                                                                                                                                                                                
            puts "[FAILED]".red                                                                                                                                                               
          end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Kernel.system` calls the given shell command. When it fails it return a `false` value.

In your case it means `git clone --bare #{path_to_bundle} #{project.repository.path_to_repo} > /dev/null 2>&1` fails.

You can check why it fails when you execute this command on the command line by hand without `> /dev/null 2>&1` .

To get the command you can at a debug print before the command

`if Kernel.system(pp("git clone --bare #{path_to_bundle} #{project.repository.path_to_repo} > /dev/null 2>&1"))`

Comment: If I check with /dev/null 2>&1. I get the output: -bash: /dev/null: Permission denied  I tried to change the chmod and chown of the dev/null and repo. But I still get the persmission denied message. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is your host a bare metal machine or some kind of vm or container? It looks like your user has no write permission to /dev/null. Which OS do you use?

Comment: I use a vm  (shell in a box)

Comment: I don't know your vm you can try `ls -l /dev/null` to check if this device exists. When it exists you don't have the permission to use. You have to ask your admin or the docs how to fix this issue.

`>/dev/null 2>&1` is not realy important. It should only silence the comment.

Comment: If chmod does not work, maybe you don't have the permission to change the permissions or some thing like apparmor prevents you from accessing this device. You can use `uname -a` to get more informations about your system. `ps -ef` can also tell some thing about whats going on on your vm.

Comment: What do you mean with silence the comment?

Comment: When you execute a command it often send some status informations to stdout or stderr. What you can see in the console. When you execute a command via script you don't need this aoutput, so you send it to "nirvana" aka `/dev/null`. You can replace `/dev/null` with every file you want for later use in your case, for instance `/tmp/output.txt` you only need sufficent write permissions for this file and enough free disk space. But keep in mind that you can leak confidential informations when you write data to a tmp folder.

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Kernel.html#method-i-system):

> system returns `true` if the command gives zero exit status, `false` for non zero exit status. Returns `nil` if command execution fails. An error status is available in `$?`.

That said: Falling into constantly in the failing state means that the system command returned `false` or `nil`. You might want to check `$?` for the reason:

```
command = Kernel.system("git clone --bare #{path_to_bundle} #{project.repository.path_to_repo} > /dev/null 2>&1")
if command
  puts "[DONE]".green
else
  puts "[FAILED]".red
  puts "Reason:"
  puts $?
end
```

Comment: If I do this I get the ouput: pid 7169(every pid has a diffrent number) exit 128 (all exits have the same number)

Comment: When you get error code 128 [this question and the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9617336/how-to-resolve-git-did-not-exit-cleanly-exit-code-128-error-on-tortoisegit) might be of interest for you.