# Authentication Issue Argo CD with Azure DevOps Server 2020 - Git Repo

Tags: git, azure-devops, argocd

### Environment:

I have the following scenario, I'm using `Argo CD (v2.0.1+33eaf11)` for deploying my `kustomize` config to a `OKD` Cluster, the config is hosted in a `Git-Repo` on the `AzureDevOps 2020` (On premise). SSL Certs are present on all sides. (Successful tried out to do a git connect from the argo CD Instance to the AzureDevOps GitRepo).

### The error I'm getting is:

- `git did not exit cleanly (exit code 128)` see https://stackoverflow.com/a/9980445/11473934

### I've tried the following:

1. Creating a PAT in AzureDevops with read rights on the repo, also tried full access.

- On Argo CD, in the connect git-repo dialog i tried the following without success:
  [image](image from argocd homepage)

  1. Try:

     - Repository URL: `https://theServer/<project>/_git/<repository>`
     - Username: `<username of PAT>`
     - Password: `<The PAT>`
  2. Try:

     - Repository URL: `https://theServer/<account>/<project>/_git/<repository>`
     - Username: something - couldn't leave it blank
     - Password: `<The PAT>`
  3. Try:

     - Generating a SSH Key using it own booth sides, using SSH
     - Resulting in FATA[0000] unknown error: remote: Command git-upload-pack '******' is not in expected format.

Is there anyone how got a similar scenario up and running? What I'm looking for is some mechanism like Access Tokens. But I'm happy with every other working solution.

Created a [issue on the argoCD github](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-cd/issues/6289).