# GitHub & Tortoisegit: git did not exit cleanly (exit code 128)

Tags: git, github, ssh, tortoisegit

i had a repository cloned and that worked very well.
Unfortunatelly i had a problem with files inside so i decided to start from new.
I deleted the repo on github and the folder on my computer.

After that i created the repo again and tried to clone it back to PC i get this error all the time.

```
git.exe clone --progress -v "git@github.com:USER/REPOSITORY.git" "E:\FOLDERNAME"
Cloning into 'E:\FOLDERNAME'...
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.


git did not exit cleanly (exit code 128) (672 ms @ 03.10.2021 01:07:48)
```

**I tried so much to solve the issue:**

- regenerate new SSH-Key(s) and stored it on github
- create another repo with a different name
- reinstalled tortoise git
- Also tried to find a index.lock (cant find)
- reconfigured Name and E-mail (also with git bash)(does these infos has to be the same than on github account?)

Its strange but allthough i reinstalled tortoise git completely new, he still displayed the correct SSH-Key path but its greyed out so also if i would like to change that i cant.

Tried all solutions from: [How to resolve "git did not exit cleanly (exit code 128)" error on TortoiseGit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9617336/how-to-resolve-git-did-not-exit-cleanly-exit-code-128-error-on-tortoisegit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution. Because of some troubleshooting solutions i changed the SSH-Client at `TortoiseGit > Settings > Network` from ssh.exe to the same that git uses. Because of that the field for the Private Key Path in TortoiseGit cloning window was greyed out.
I entered now the `TortoiseGitPlink.exe` so the field was released, now i was able to set the new private key path.

Unfortunatelly now i got the error `No supported authentication methods available (Sever sent: public key)`.
So i changed the SSH-Client back to `ssh.exe` (without direct path) and now it worked fine!

I really dont know what exatly was wrong but it works now so im happy.

Answer (score 1):

Try first to clone it directly from command-line:

```
git -c "core.sshcommand='ssh -Tv'" clone --progress -v "git@github.com:USER/REPOSITORY.git" "E:\FOLDERNAME"
```

The `core.sshcommand='ssh -Tv'` will tell you if you are reading the correct SSH key.

Check you don't have any `SSH_xxx` or `GIT_SSHxxx` environment variable.

Once the clone is working from command-line, you can start and try it through TortoiseGit.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. No environment variable setted. 
$ git -c "core.sshcommand='ssh -Tv'" clone --progress -v "git@github.com:USER/REPOSITORY.git" "E:\FOLDERNAME"
Cloning into 'E:\FOLDERNAME'...
'ssh -Tv': ssh -Tv: command not found
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Comment: TortoiseGit -> Show Environment Variables shows a file (PatB03E.tmp) which contains Variables but i was not able to find them over wondows settings.  GIT_SSH=C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\ssh.exe
SVN_SSH=C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\ssh.exe
DISPLAY=:9999
SSH_ASKPASS=C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin\SshAskPass.exe
GIT_ASKPASS=C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin\SshAskPass.exe
GIT_ASK_YESNO=C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin\SshAskPass.exe

Comment: @C.Hillert Yes, never use putty or Tortoise SSH. Always use the openSSH one coming with Git For Windows.